# Show relationships between classes in different packages in a UML class diagram

Tags: c#, class, uml, diagram

Would I draw the Arrow out of one package from one class to another or from one package to the other package that the classes are in?

Comment: I think the Enterprise version of Visual Studio does this already.

Comment: I am creating the diagram in an external graphics app, so how would I display it there?

Answer (score 1):

Simply draw the relations "as usual". You can show the packages enlarged so the classes contained inside will appear as being inside. However, there is no need to show the packages. You could as well create package diagrams with just the classes inside and no relations to emphasize the package character.

In general you are free to show whatever fits best / transports the message you want to be shown.

---

It's recommended to use an UML modeling tool rather than a drawing tool which does not have semantic for elements but only graphic information.